# How to make different color of markers for a map using amchart5

Tags: javascript, jquery, maps, amcharts, amcharts5

I want to color markers in the map of amchart5 dynamically. Each marker has to get the color that i want. In my data I have many points where each point has latitude, Longitude, url, color, zoom level etc. I want marker in the map to color according to the color mentioned in the data

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.